# Rails - ERROR: Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-elcapitan

My machine using OSX El Capitan. I already follow the instructions one by one. It's working fine until I need to install rails, something unwanted happened. BTW I already installed Xcode command line tools but still not fix even I restart the terminal and machine. I got this error message.

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.4
```

Error message

```
Last login: Sat Nov  7 15:07:53 on ttys000
Mohammads-MacBook-Air% gem install rails -v 4.2.4
Ignoring curb-0.8.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb --version 0.8.8
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ZERO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151107-786-tg78i0.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Ignoring curb-0.8.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb --version 0.8.8
-----
The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.

To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ZERO/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ZERO/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ZERO/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
Mohammads-MacBook-Air%
```

Reference: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. Using rvm to handel it.

```
rvm install ruby-2.1.1
rvm 2.1.1
gem install rails -v 4.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There error message tells you:

> The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
>   which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.
>
> To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
>   terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
>   select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
>   Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
>   version and run it.

Unfortunately this error message is sometimes misleading. What the message really tries to tell you is that it *just wasn't able to use the Command Line Tools*. That does not necessarily mean they are not installed - it might mean that you just did not accept the license agreement yet.

I noticed that this is a common problem after installing Xcode and it recurs after updating to newer versions of Xcode. I recommened to do the follow steps after each installation or upgrade of Xcode:

- Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
- Try to reinstall the Command Line Tools

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. If `xcode-select --install` does not work try to start the install `Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

Opening Xcode and accepting the license agreement fixed this error for me. Afterwards, could run `sudo gem install rails` successfully.